# WebDriverMananager in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am trying to figure out how to do cross browser using WebDriverManager in my test base?
I know how to do one browser at a time:

```
WebDriverManager.chromdriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

So do I use `if` and `else` statements or?
Thanks for any leads and have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0):

[WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) provides a *generic manager* that can be used for cross-browser testing. You can use this feature through the method `getInstance()`, invoked using the following options:

- `getInstance(Class<?> webDriverClass)`
- `getInstance(DriverManagerType driverManagerType)`
- `getInstance(String browserName)`

You can see more info and examples in the [WebDriverManager documentation](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#generic-manager).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate this feature!

Comment: @Boni Garcia, please write a working code example demonstrating cross-browser testing with WebDriverManager